# Passing both app and io to a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, socket.io

From my `server.js`:

```
var app  = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(port,function (){
       console.log('Listening is at ' + port);  
});
```

Now I am trying to pass both my `app` and `io` to a module:

```
require('./routes/moduleX.js')(app,io);
```

In `./routes/moduleX.js`:

```
module.exports = function(app,io){

      app.get('/moduleXX',function(req,res){ /
           res.render('moduleXX.ejs');

           var dataToBeSent = {
                  YYYY: 10,
                  NNNNN: 5,
                  TTTTT: [2,4,5,6,7],
           };

           io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
                  console.log('Client Connected');
            socket.emit('subReady', { prep: dataToBeSent });
           });      

      });
     }
```

I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined`

My question is why `io` is undefined here? and how to do it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Change the following code

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client Connected');
    socket.emit('subReady', { prep: dataToBeSent });
});
```

to

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client Connected');
    socket.emit('subReady', { prep: dataToBeSent });
});
```

Comment: Modified to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Comment: I've got the code above working on my location machine, have you installed the "socket.io" module correctly?